# Rewrite a Regular Expression without Catastrophic Backtracking?

Tags: java, regex, sonarqube

I was wondering if anyone could examine this regular expression and rewrite it without catastrophic backtracking?  My SonarQube seems to be upset.  ;)

```
String NEGATIVE = "(.*?[^0-9]+?)-([0-9.]+?.*?)";
```

According to the Java code, it is attempting use this expression to help find and replace negative number signs with tilde characters.

```
// Replace any negative number signs as they will
// be confused with the subtraction operator.
expression = expression.replaceAll(NEGATIVE, "$1~$2").replaceFirst("^-", "~");
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the patten `(.*?[^0-9]+?)-([0-9.]+?.*?)` the non greedy part `.*?` at the end can be omitted, as it will not match any characters.

This part `[0-9.]+?` will only match 1 character as the quantifier is non greedy so the quantifier can be omitted (as the following `.*?` does not match any character)

You can use lookarounds with just a single character in the assertions:

```
(?<!\d)-(?=\d)
```

- `(?<!\d)` Negative lookbehind, assert not a digit directly to the left of the current position
- `-` Match a hyphen
- `(?=\d)` Positive lookahead, assert a digit directly to the right of the current positions

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/K8tUVK/1)

Comment: Thanks.  Both answers at this time from @thefourthbird and @StevenSpungin seem viable, so I am going with the shorter one.  I have to modify though as it seems decimal points should be handled (as seen in the original) and is not here.  This is what I came up with -> `(?<!\d)-(?=[\d.])`.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This will match all negative signs before digits in basic expressions. Execute, and then replace the entire match with a `~`.

You did not post your input set, so there might be other cases that need to be coded.

```
(?<=[-+*\/0-9 ]|^)-(?=[\d]+)
```

Here are some examples of replacements
https://regex101.com/r/3H30tU/1https://regex101.com/r/3H30tU/1